# Length of String as extension of String

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, count

I know that there will be lots of pointers to duplicates but this worked before I updated to xcode 6.3 and now it has a problem with it.

The script:

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count:Int) -> String {
        var getSelf = self as String
        var stringLength = count(getSelf.utf16)

        let substringIndex = (stringLength < count) ? 0 : stringLength - count

        return self.substringToIndex(advance(self.startIndex, substringIndex))
    }
}
```

Error : Cannot invoke 'count' with an argument of list of type '(String.UTF16View)'

---

I also want to point out that this new method for counting works everywhere else I have used out (outside of this extension).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count` is the name of your extension method parameter and hides the
Swift library function `count()`. You can rename the parameter
or call

```
var stringLength = Swift.count(getSelf.utf16)
```

explicitly.

But note that counting the number of UTF-16 code units is wrong here, it should be

```
var stringLength = Swift.count(getSelf)
```

to count the number of characters in the string, because that is what
`advance()` also counts. You can verify that easily with

```
let foo = "".removeCharsFromEnd(1)
println(foo)
```

Here is a simplified version of your method:

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count : Int) -> String {
        precondition(count >= 0, "Attempt to call removeCharsFromEnd() with a negative count")
        // Decrement `endIndex` by `count`, but not beyond `startIndex`:
        let idx = advance(self.endIndex, -count, self.startIndex)
        return self.substringToIndex(idx)
    }
}
```

using the three-argument version of `advance()` with a negative distance.

Update for **Swift 2/Xcode 7:**

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count : Int) -> String {
        precondition(count >= 0, "Attempt to call removeCharsFromEnd() with a negative count")
        // Decrement `endIndex` by `count`, but not beyond `startIndex`:
        let idx = self.endIndex.advancedBy(-count, limit: self.startIndex)
        return self.substringToIndex(idx)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thank you.  That worked.  But why is it that count doesn't need "swift" prior but this does?

Comment: @WadeCantley:`count(getSelf.utf16)` gives the same error in Xcode 6.2.  Perhaps you used `countElements()` or `getSelf.utf16Count` before ?

Comment: I was using getSelf.utf16Count in this particularly function.

However, there are other places in my code where I transitioned to count(someString.utf16) without issue.  This is the only place where I have had to put in "Swift.".  I was just wondering if there was something that required it.  I am just trying to figure out some reason between the two so that next time I know when to apply it.

Comment: @WadeCantley: The problem occurs only because your method parameter `(count:Int)` uses the same name "count" as the library function.

Comment: Yes.. yes thanks... I see that now.  That makes much more sense, especially since the prior method was "getSelf.utf16Count".

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

extension String {
    func removeCharsFromEnd(n:Int) -> String {
        return substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex, end: advance(startIndex, count(self) < n ? 0 : count(self)-n )))
    }
}

"Hello, playground".removeCharsFromEnd(3)  // "Hello, playgro"
"".removeCharsFromEnd(1)             // ""
```

you can also use subscript:

```
extension String {
    subscript(index: Int) -> String? {
        guard index >= 0 && index < characters.count else { return nil }
        return String(self[startIndex.advancedBy(index)])
    }
    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> String? {
        guard
            range.startIndex >= 0 &&
            range.endIndex <= characters.count &&
            startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex) <= endIndex &&
            startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex) >= startIndex &&
            range.startIndex.distanceTo(range.endIndex) <= characters.count
        else { return nil }
        return self[startIndex.advancedBy(range.startIndex)..<startIndex.advancedBy(range.endIndex)]
    }
}

"Hello, playground"[0...4] // "Hello"
"Hello, playground"[5]      // ","
"Hello, playground"[7...16]  // "playground"

""[1]  // ""
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a different way to approach the general function, however it still uses "count(self)" which didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried with utf16count but it didn't work as expected as noted by Marting R  about the way advance counts it.

Comment: Thanks, the additional info is helpful.  Much appreciated.