# Generic 'Print' Swift 2.0 Array Extension

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, element, swift2

Trying to make an generic extension to Array that prints all values in the array.
This worked before swift 2.0.

```
extension Array {
   func print() {
      for t:Element in self {
         print(t)
      }
   }
}
```

I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Element' to expected argument type '()'

Perhaps ensuring that Element is 'Printable' via a Protocol would solve it, however I can't find said protocol anywhere.

Comment: Same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548031/length-of-string-as-extension-of-string: Your extension method "print" hides the library "print" function -> use `Swift.print(t)` (*if* you really need a custom print method).

Comment: Btw, that code does not compile with Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) either.

Comment: `Printable` has been renamed to `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: @MartinR the code compiled before Swift 2.0, can't remember what Xcode version, but Element would need to be replaced with T. Thanks a lot for the solution - it has been a long day and naming functions has never been my strong point!